# Partitions of $\mathbb{R}^+$ into subset closed by sum and product

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

Suppose we can partition $\mathbb{R}$ into two subset $A,B$, both non empty and closed by sum and product. Let $0\in A$, and suppose that exists $b\in B$. Then $b^2\in B$. Now, $-b\in B$, cause if $-b\in A$ we would have $(-b)^2=b^2\in A$. Now, $0=b+(-b)\in B$, absurd. So $B$ must be empty, and the required partition doesn't exists.

Now we can ask the same question for $\mathbb{R}^+$. I guess that also in this case there are no such partition. Clearly the argument above doesn't work, cause we can't use negative numbers. Note also that a partition into subset closed only by sum exists: infact
let $x_i$ an Hamel base of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$:
$$A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^+:x=\alpha_1x_1+\ldots,\quad\alpha_1\geq 0\}$$
$$B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^+:x=\alpha_1x_1+\ldots,\quad\alpha_1\leq 0\}$$
satisfies the request. 
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Suppose $1\in A$. Then $\frac 1 n\in A$, so $\mathbb Q\subseteq A$, and $A$ contains all algebraic real numbers. Just a thought.

Comment: In the sum only partition we need to separate the sets by the sign of the earliest nonzero $\alpha$.  As written, any number with $\alpha_1=0$ goes into both sets.  We can then place $0$ into either one.